# Blocking VPNs on Android devices

Tags: android, security, vpn

I want to make an android application that runs at background. And it will block EVERY VPNs' connection. The purpose of the project is to protect the children from harmful content.

Is it technically possible to block every VPNs on Android devices by running an application at background?

For this I have googled many sites and links. But, I haven't got any answer relevant to my requirement.

Answer (score 2):

> And it will block EVERY VPNs'

**Perhaps** [Device Administration](https://developer.android.com/work/device-management-policy.html) features may be a way to go, but if not, then you are out of luck unless you target rooted devices.

> The purpose of the project is to protect the children from harmful content

This reasoning sounds so ridiculous if you ask me. You seem to new in Internets if you think this will give any benefits.